# Why does Flowtype allow assigning empty object ({}) to a type?

Tags: flowtype

Can someone explain to me why `a2` doesn't give any error?

```
type A = {
 name: string;
 type: number;
}; 

const a1: A = null; // NOT OK
const a2: A = {}; // OK
const a3: A = { name: "aaa" }; // NOT OK
const a4: A = { name: "aaa", type: 6 }; // OK
```

I tried the same thing in Typescript and it `a2` doesn't compile. And I agree with Typescript. Why does Flowtype think it's ok? Is there a setting which would allow me to make it not ok?

Comment: I know I could use exact-type to make it fail, but that's not I want. It works as expected on Typescript, but not on Flow. Why?

Comment: I think it is related to [issue #2327](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2327).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{}` seems to be a special thing - unsealed object (https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-unsealed-objects). The idea is to allow you to fill the object step by step:

```
type A = {
 name: string;
 type: number;
}; 

const a2: A = {};
a2.name = "FOO";
a2.type = 3;
```

There seems to be a lot of confusion about how it should work exactly in various different situations:

- https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2327
- https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2977